# python selenium: Not able to click in a tree node element using find_element_by_xpath or id

Tags: python, selenium

I use selenium in python to inspect elements. I have an html code below. I have to inspect some element (node tree) but I am not able to click on it. I would like to know how to click on nodes to open other child nodes.

[image]

I would like to click in a "+" icon but these two elements have the same "title", same "id" same "name", same "src" ...

[image]

I try to use `Find_by_xpath()`, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pick some surrounding elements in such case to uniquely identify the element.

In your case span id i.e. `nodeHandle` is identical but parent div has unique id so you can use as following -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='treenode_DocumentTypeFolderManagerWidget_0_3']/span[@id='nodeHandle']")
```